# SQL, Range between

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012

I have this:

```
 SELECT 

 firstname, lastname, Sexe, Weight,
 sum(E.Weight) OVER (ORDER BY E.Height 
                     RANGE BETWEEN 10 PRECEDING AND 5 FOLLOWING ) AS SumHeight

 FROM HR.Employees AS E
 ORDER BY E.Height
```

But I get this error:

> RANGE is only supported with UNBOUNDED and CURRENT ROW window frame delimiters.

Comment: Isn't range between and (< >) same?

Comment: You mean like this: SELECT firstname, lastname, Sexe, Weight,
 sum(E.Weight) OVER (ORDER BY E.Height <> BETWEEN 10 PRECEDING AND 5 FOLLOWING ) AS SumHeight

 FROM HR.Employees AS E
 ORDER BY E.Height      that doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) (T-SQL OVER Clause) shows that:

> <unsigned value specification> PRECEDING:
>       Specified with <unsigned value specification> to indicate the number of rows or values to precede the current row. This
>   specification is not allowed for RANGE.

So your <window frame preceding> and <window frame following> in the RANGE specification can only use UNBOUNDED PRECEDING|CURRENT ROW, respectively UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING|CURRENT ROW.

You are probably looking for ROWS i/o RANGE?

Comment: Ok, but what is the alternative in SQL2012?

Comment: @savantKing use `ROWS BETWEEN ... AND ...`

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much what it says - you've got to have either unbounded or current row at the ends of a range.

You can't do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should have use `ROWS` instead of `RANGE`:

```
SELECT 
 firstname, lastname, Sexe, Weight,
 SUM(E.Weight) OVER (ORDER BY E.Height 
                 ROWS BETWEEN 10 PRECEDING AND 5 FOLLOWING ) AS SumHeight
 FROM HR.Employees AS E
 ORDER BY E.Height
```

Otherwise if you have to use `RANGE` then you have to what it suggest i.e. use `UNBOUNDED` and/or `CURRENT_ROW` delimiters:

```
SELECT 
 firstname, lastname, Sexe, Weight,
 SUM(E.Weight) OVER (ORDER BY E.Height 
                 RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS SumHeight
 FROM HR.Employees AS E
 ORDER BY E.Height
```

The above of course does not meet what you need but just showing you the possible way to use it.